# Is it possible to convert between Socket and TcpClient objects?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient, system.net

Here's another C#/.NET question based merely on curiousity more than an immediate *need* ...

If you had a `Socket` instance and you wanted to wrap it in the higher-level `TcpClient` class, is that possible and how would you do it?

Conversely if you have an instance of `TcpClient`, is it possible to get the underlying `Socket`?

Comment: Apparently there's the very obvious "Client" property which I completely missed!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> If you had a Socket instance and you
>   wanted to wrap it in the higher-level
>   TcpClient class, is that possible and
>   how would you do it?

```
Socket socket = ...;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Client = socket;
```

> Conversely if you have an instance of
>   TcpClient, is it possible to get the
>   underlying Socket?

Get the underlying Socket using [TcpClient.Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client.aspx) property.

Answer (score 3):

From TcpClient to Socket is very easy. `tcpClientInstance.Client` is the underlying Socket instance.